# iterate through each point on a line/path in java

Tags: java, path, iterator, line, point

I'm new to using iterators and was wondering how one would iterate through each point on a line segment (Line2D.Double, to be precise) -- I need to check to see if each point on the line fulfills certain requirements.

Also, given a path object (like GeneralPath), how would you do the same thing (iterate through each point on the outline of the shape)?

Ideally I'd like something like this (with either a line or a path):

```
Line2D line = new Line2D.Double(p1,p2);
for (Point2D point : line)
{
   point.callSomeMethod();
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There seems to be nothing in the Java API that makes Bresenham's algorithm user-visible. [So I wrote a class that iterates over a line.](http://snipt.net/nikoschwarz/iterate-all-points-on-a-line-using-bresenhams-algorithm)

You can use it like this:

```
List<Point2D> points = new ArrayList<Point2D>();
Line2D line = new Line2D.Double(0, 0, 8, 4);
Point2D current;

for (Iterator<Point2D> it = new LineIterator(line); it.hasNext();) {
    current = it.next();
    points.add(current);
}

assertThat(points.toString(), 
    is("[Point2D.Double[0.0, 0.0], Point2D.Double[1.0, 0.0], " +
        "Point2D.Double[2.0, 1.0], Point2D.Double[3.0, 1.0], " +
        "Point2D.Double[4.0, 2.0], Point2D.Double[5.0, 2.0], " +
        "Point2D.Double[6.0, 3.0], Point2D.Double[7.0, 3.0], " +
        "Point2D.Double[8.0, 4.0]]"));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man, your logic for getting all points lie on line are great. and such it work very well for me.

Comment: Link seems outdated. Can you update it or provide the code as part of your answer?

Answer (score 1):

This will be slow because it will generate a new object for each point. If you need a faster solution, you might want to look into implementing the loop yourself, using the [Bresenham algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm).

Comment: This may or may not be true. Escapa analysis style optimizations make it unnecessary to make new objects each time. Still up-voted, because it's the only the answer that makes at least a bit of sense.

Comment: True, the JVM could 'optimize away' the object.

Answer (score 0):

Although your question is missing a lot of relevant info (ie I'm guessing a lot about your classes), the cleanest loop code is the `foreach` syntax:

```
GeneralPath path = ...;
for (Line2D.Double point : path.getPoints()) {
    // do something
}
```

Note however that you can not modify the object being iterated over with this kind of loop.

Comment: I am looking for something almost exactly like that foreach loop, but I just tried it and GeneralPath does not have a method called getPoints() (neither does Line2D)... Also, wouldn't I want to do for (_Point2D_...), not Line2D, in the argument?

Answer (score 0):

Check the type returned:

- `PathIterator.SEG_MOVETO`
- `PathIterator.SEG_LINETO`
- `PathIterator.SEG_QUADTO`
- `PathIterator.SEG_CUBICTO`
- `PathIterator.SEG_CLOSE`

Code:

```
PathIterator pi = path.getPathIterator(null);

while (pi.isDone() == false) {
    double[] coordinates = new double[6];
    int type = pi.currentSegment(coordinates);
    pi.next();
}
```

Comment: but, (from my limited understanding of iterators) wouldn't this just give me the start/end points of each segment of the path, not every single point on the path?

Comment: you are right, but on a line, you can get unlimited number of point. so if you get start and end point for a line segment, why don't you calculate yourself base on the precision you want?

Comment: Edited: I misunderstand your question, see the previous comment is enough, remember two point form, you can get the coordinate yourself. //I think you can use Line2D.Double(double X1, double Y1, double X2, double Y2) to create the Line2D first, then use the Line2D method contains(double x, double y) to check if the point is on the line

Answer (score 0):

Use FlatteningPathIterator passing your Shape's path iterator.