# How to get Line coordinates after applying transform in Graphics2D?

Tags: java, awt, java-2d, graphics2d, affinetransform

How can I get the line coordinates after applying graphics2d transformation? Here is the code:

```
double startX = 100;
double startY = 100;
double endX   = 500;
double endY   = 500;

AffineTransform rotation = new AffineTransform();      
double angle = Math.toRadians(90);
rotation.rotate(angle, 200, 200); 

Graphics2D brush = (Graphics2D) g;
Line2D.Double line = new Line2D.Double(startX, startY, endX, endY);  
brush.setTransform(rotation);
brush.draw(line);
```

Comment: Huh?  If the transform is correct & set to the graphics instance, you should be able to use the original co-ordinates in whatever methods are needed, and the transform will be done automatically.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I don't need to perform another transform. Just want new coordinates (x1,y1,x2,y2) of the line after applying transform. That will be off-course different from the coordinates before transform. Thanks

Comment: 1) *"Just want new coordinates.."*  No offense intended, but I don't really care *what* you want, I am trying to find out *why* you want it.  What is the application feature you intend to implement as a result of knowing that information?  There might be easier ways to implement it than what you are attempting now. 2) Do you intend to ignore the advice about posting an SSCCE?  I was hoping it might explain the 'why?'.  Note that if you are intending to ignore it, that 'ignoring' can go both ways.  It's not as if I don't have other things to do, or other people to help..

Comment: I will post an SSCCE, no problem. I want new coordinates, because I want to draw 2 other line starting from each vertex of transformed line. Also, I want to draw 4 small circles along the transformed line.

Comment: Why not add the lines and circles to a `GeneralPath` or compound `Shape` that is transformed as a whole?

Comment: I am new to Graphics2D, will give GeneralPath a try. Thanks.

Comment: I have to create 2 such lines each with 4 circles. Then I will apply random transform on both lines. Will then I be able to find if any of circle on one line overlaps a circle in other line using GeneralPath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont see any "great" way of doing this but heres what I got. You can use a `PathIterator` object to get the result of the line after the rotation is applied. From there you can loop through the coordinates inside the `PathIterator` and get your x and y coordinates.

Heres an awnser that has a cleaner way of grabbing out the coordinates if your interested [iterate through each point on a line/path in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339328/iterate-through-each-point-on-a-line-path-in-java)

Also if you plan to use this in any sort of graphics I would not recommend doing this process inside your paint method.

```
double startX = 100;
double startY = 100;
double endX   = 500;
double endY   = 500;

AffineTransform rotation = new AffineTransform();      
double angle = Math.toRadians(90);
rotation.rotate(angle, 200, 200); 

Line2D.Double line = new Line2D.Double(startX, startY, endX, endY);
PathIterator it = line.getPathIterator(rotation);
while(!it.isDone()) {
    double [] values = new double[6];
    it.currentSegment(values);
    System.out.println("["+values[0] + ", " + values[1] + "]");
    it.next();
}
```

Also I noticed some comments about using a Paths instead of your inital line. I agree that a path should be used whenever you need to be applying transforms for a "shape" due to their built in methods for handling it. Heres an example of using a path instead of your Line2D

```
double startX = 100;
double startY = 100;
double endX   = 500;
double endY   = 500;

AffineTransform rotation = new AffineTransform();      
double angle = Math.toRadians(90);
rotation.rotate(angle, 200, 200); 

Path2D path = new Path2D.Double();
path.moveTo(startX, startY);
path.lineTo(endX, endY);

path.transform(rotation);

double [] values = new double[6];
for(PathIterator it = path.getPathIterator(null); !it.isDone();) {
    it.currentSegment(values);
    System.out.println("["+values[0] + ", " + values[1] + "]");
    it.next();
}
```