# How to make an image follow a line?

Tags: java, swing

Hello I have a program that displays a line, but the line is always moving (not very fast). I would like an image to follow the line starting at one end and ending at the other end. How can I achieve this? Here is the code I use to display the line and image:

```
if (p1sel) {
    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    g.drawLine((int) px+25, (int) py+25, (int) px1+25, (int) py1+25);
}

if (p2sel) {
    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    g.drawLine((int) px1+25, (int) py1+25, (int) px+25, (int) py+25);
}

ImageIcon i12w2 = new ImageIcon("res/planets/ship.png");
img = i12w2.getImage();
g.drawImage(img, (int) x, (int) y, null);
```

Comment: google equation for points on a line

Comment: Or you could try using `LineIterator` as seen in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339328/iterate-through-each-point-on-a-line-path-in-java

Comment: Just move it along points on the line every x ms.