# How to get all the points of a drawn line

Tags: java

If I draw a line with

```
g.drawLine(x, y, width, height);
```

How can I know the coordinates of the pixels that make up this line knowing only the starting and ending points?

Comment: With what interval? There are a potentially *infinite* number of points along a given line, as the interval along the line tends to zero.

Comment: I do not understand

Comment: I know that a line is made of points

Comment: A straight horizontal line from (0,0) to (1,0) has the intermediate points (0.1,0), (0.2,0), (0.3,0).... if you are stepping in increments of 0.1. If you are stepping in increments of 0.01 you have (0.01,0), (0.02,0), (0.03,0)... Stepping by an infinitesimal amount would give you an infinite number of points.

Comment: Considering you're talking about graphics, maybe a better or more useful question would be "what pixels form this line?" but you have not given us any context so this is currently impossible to answer

Comment: Exactly, it would be more appropriate to know which pixels form a line knowing only the points of the ends

Comment: Edit your question then

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339328/iterate-through-each-point-on-a-line-path-in-java try this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iterate through each point on a line/path in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339328/iterate-through-each-point-on-a-line-path-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using basic Math. For there are infinite points on a line you cannot fill an array with all the points. So may be:

```
g.drawLine(0, 1, 10, 20);

public double line1(int x){
  return (1+x*2)
}
```